# Is there a way to have a split, multi-user Access database that queries one shared excel file?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I ran into a multi-user related problem in my MS Access application.

I have a split database, with multiple front-ends and multiple back-ends. The file locations of the backend databases are stored in an Excel file. The front-end contains a combo box, of which the source is a query that reads the data from the excel file:
This enables the users to switch between the different be-databases.

```
SELECT XL.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM [Speicherorte BE_DB$] AS xlData IN 'Z:\LocationXYZ\Speicherort_BE_DB.XLSX'[Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=yes;IMEX=0;ACCDB=Yes])  AS XL
ORDER BY gemeinde;
```

However, I noticed that doing so, this doesn't allow for multiple users at the same time.
Error: "External table is not in the expected format"

This error does not occur when only one person is using the application.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Maybe only query the excel file once upon startup and then have "static values" in the combo box for the rest of the time?

Thx in advance and best regards,
Michael

Comment: Your observation is correct. So, move that information from Excel to a new, small Access database and establish a static link to the table.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried just that and it works like a charm